# compiling clojurescript and angularjs in advanced mode

Tags: clojurescript

I am having problems with getting a simple clojurescript program to compile right in advanced mode. For example, here is a simple program

```
(ns cljs-basics.core)

(.write js/document "hello, cljs")

(def basicsApp (.module js/angular "basics" (array)))

(def testController 
  (.controller basicsApp "TestCtrl" (fn [$scope])))
(aset testController "$inject" (array "$scope"))
```

and the html file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="basics" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Simple CLJS</title>
    <script src="components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="js/basic.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="TestCtrl">
    {{testvar}}
</body>
</html>
```

the code is running fine on :simple but when I turn on :advanced, it just does not work. The `.controller` and `.module` calls gets compiled to symbols and so I get

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'Uf' basic.js:5105
Uncaught Error: No module: basics
```

Is there a way to somehow include the angular.js file so that the compiler can minify everything together?

Answer (score 2):

If you include the appropriate 'externs' file, :advanced mode compilation won't rename symbols defined in the external library. The externs file for angular can be found at:

https://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/source/browse/contrib/externs/angular.js

If you're using cljsbuild, the Leiningen compiler configuration looks like the following:

```
:cljsbuild {
    :builds [
        {
            :source-paths ["src"]
            :compiler {
                :output-to "target/main.js"
                :optimizations :advanced
                :externs ["externs/angular.js"]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Angular does not support advanced compilation yet. But they are working on it.

Answer (score 0):

An interesting thing is the library itself can be used as extern file because all Closure compiler care about extern files is defined symbols (plain javascript objects and the symbols inside them - attributes, methods and nested objects).

Also, I made a library that help avoiding writing extern files:
https://github.com/myguidingstar/fence